# I am trying to add information into two tables at the same time. One table

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, mysql-error-1064

Error when trying to populate table

I am wanting to input data into a single row within a table, the first set of data is generated from a form input and the second is the auto-increment from another table.

```
INSERT INTO Bar_Location2 (`Bar_Admitted`) VALUES ("{57}");<br>
INSERT INTO Bar_Location2 (Your_ID) SELECT Your_ID FROM Your_Detail;
```

I can execute each query separately and the table will populate (unfortunately on separate rows), but I get the following error when I combine the two:

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO Bar_Location2 (Your_ID) SELECT Your_ID FROM Your_Detail' at line 2 SQL=INSERT INTO Bar_Location2 (`Bar_Admitted`) VALUES ("{57}"); INSERT INTO Bar_Location2 (Your_ID) SELECT Your_ID FROM Your_Detail;
```

I have also tried:

```
START TRANSACTION;<br>
INSERT INTO Bar_Location2 (`Bar_Admitted`) VALUES ("{57}");<br> 
INSERT INTO Bar_Location2 (Your_ID) SELECT Your_ID FROM Your_Detail;<br>
COMMIT;
```

and again I get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

try without braces

```
INSERT INTO Bar_Location2 (Bar_Admitted) VALUES ("57");
```

and in this form of query

```
 START TRANSACTION
 INSERT INTO Bar_Location2 (`Bar_Admitted`) VALUES ("57");
 INSERT INTO Bar_Location2 (Your_ID) SELECT Your_Detail.Your_ID FROM Your_Detail;
 COMMIT;
 END OF TRANSACTION
```

Comment: I am using a module for joomla called form maker.  This module gives me the option for MySQL mapping with the ability to create my own query, however using anything other than one query at a time causes the error code whether I use brackets or not